# Basic C++ error. Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'matrix' was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-c++, matrix, runtime-error

I am just starting to make a matrix calculator and am frustrated to have run into problems so early. 
I am making a 3x3 Matrix calculator and am having problems entering values to the array, it runs fine as far as I can tell until "cin  matrix[2][2];" when I get an error "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'matrix' was corrupted." My guess would be I am entering outside the array and so it is undefined but I cannot see how I am, thanks for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double matrix[2][2];

   for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=2;j++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter value: ["<<i+1<<"]["<<j+1<<"] of your 3x3 vector.\n";
        cin>>matrix[i][j];
    }
}
   cout<<matrix[1][2];

  cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: declare your as matrix[3][3]

Comment: So stupid, I knew the cause of the error and still couldn't see it. Thanks for the help, I understand why too. Although the first index is 0, it still must be declared as 3x3. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the indexing of arrays in c++(and in fact in many programming languages)begins from 0.But when you specify the size you don't count from 0.So it should be-

```
double matrix[3][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

If an array has N elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, N-1]` So in your case when N is equal to 2 the valid range of indices will be [0, 1].

So if you want to have a 3 x 3 two-dimensional array then the number of elements N has to be equal to 3 and the valid range of indices will be [0, 2]

So in C/C++ there is used usually the following condition in loops

```
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
```

That do not make some mistakes with ranges try always to use symbolic names for sizes of arrays. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int N = 3;
   double matrix[N][N];

   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ )
      {
         cout< << "Enter value: [" << i+1 << "][" << j+1 << "] of your " 
               << N << 'x' << N << " vector.\n";
         cin>>matrix[i][j];
      }
   }

   cout << matrix[1][2];

   cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```